# Is there a way to make a "virtual" variable in a C++ base class?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have a base class with a pointer that needs to get initialized specifically in the constructor of all sub classes. How can I ensure that this variable gets initialized in the subclasses' constructors? I essentially want the same functionality as making a pure virtual function, except with a pointer to an object. Is there a way to do that?

My code looks something like this:

A.hpp:

```cpp
class A {
protected:
    A();
    X *pointer;
};
```

B.hpp:

```cpp
class B : public A {
public:
        B();
};
```

B.cpp:

```cpp
B::B() : A() {
    // how do i make sure pointer gets initialized here?
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not skip storing pointer in base class?

Comment: The "normal" way would be to pass a pointer into the constructor and have the pointer be initialized with it.  The derived constructor calls the base class and passes the pointer to it.  There is not special mechanism needed.

Comment: You are probably overthinking this. Just initialize X to nullptr or NULL in the constructor of A. Then initialize it properly in the constructor of the derived classes.  ASSERT liberally in a method in A is invoked in which X has not been initialized.

Comment: Make your default c'tor private, forcing derived classes to call the c'tor taking a pointer argument.

Comment: @IInspectable: The compiler won't even generate a default constructor if you define one taking a pointer.

Comment: @Ben That's true. My habit to declare private default c'tors for documentation purposes got me there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change constructor of base class:

```
class A {
protected:
    explicit A(X* pointer);
    X *pointer;
};
```

And so child have to give value, as:

```
class B : public A {
public:
        B() : A(nullptr) {}
        explicit B(X* x) : A(x) {}
};
```

Comment: But which class is responsible for de-allocation? Is that clear?

Comment: @user2672165: I would say the one who create it. Here `X` is not owned neither by B nor A. Else, I would change the prototype to take a `std::unique_ptr<X>`.

Answer (score 5):

Just define arguments for the base class constructor:

```
class A {
protected:
    A(X* ptr) : pointer(ptr) {}
    X *pointer;
};
```

Then the derived class is required to pass those in its *ctor-initializer* list:

```
B::B() : A(/* value of pointer must be passed here*/)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd make all data members `private` as `protected` still means that you won't ever be able to change the interface. Making the data member `private` also hints at how to make sure it is provided by the derived class: give the base class a constructor which requires a suitable pointer to be passed in. If you want to make sure that the most derived class passes in a pointer, make the base class a `virtual` base:

```
class A {
    X* pointer;
public:
    A(X* p): pointer(p) {}
};

class B
    : public A {
public:
    B(): A(new X) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, current virtual tables cannot (portably) *directly* contain "virtual data", that is meta-data common to the class level.

You could make a virtual method return a pointer to some `X` ...

You could also use [typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/) i.e. [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) (in C++11). For example you might define a static hash-table

```
static std::unordered_map<std::typeinfo,X*> map;
X* getX() { return map[typeid(this)]; };
```

It is then up to you to fill the `map` appropriately.

Comment: "meta-data common to the class" would not be initialized in a constructor, hence that isn't what he is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It would be enough if the base class would initialize that variable itself by having a constructor with a parameter that contains the initialization value.

```
class A {
protected:
    A( X * thePointer );
    X *pointer;
};
```

In this case any derived class has to explicitly call the base class constructor and specify a required value.

```
B::B() : A( thePointer ) {
    // how do i make sure pointer gets initialized here?
}
```