# Like, virtual function can we make a variable virtual in c++

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

when a base class pointer points to the object of it's derived class and if a function being overridden we use virtual function to solve the problem . So that we can access the own function of derived class using the pointer.
Like this , i was thinking that if there a way which can be applied on virtual keyword in variable , so that we can access the latest version of a variable in derived class using pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
public:
int x;//but what about this , if we add virtual keyword here.
    //it will give error if trying to do so .
    //but can you tell me what can i do if i want to make use of it as virtual function
    //if not please tell me why
virtual void display(void) //to call the recent version of display function we make use of virtual here
{
    cout << "base\n";
}
};
class derived : public base
{
public:
int x;
void display(void)
{
    cout << "derived\n";
}
};
int main(void)
{
    base *p;
    base ob1;
    derived ob2;
    p=&ob2;
    p->x=100;//here i want to set 100 to the x of derived class not that x which has been inherited
            //But it sets to the x of base class which i dont wanted
    p->display();//here we can access the latest version of display function in derived class
    return 0;
}
```

Please, No body ask me why i want to do so.I don't have any intention to do in my real code. i asked for the curiosity.

Comment: not really, but you can declare the variable normally and declare operators to access the variable in your class if that helps, and you can make the operators virtual

Comment: You can make a virtual accessor that returns a reference. You can't make all variable access virtual by default.

Comment: What would it mean to have a virtual data member ? How would it be different from a regular data member ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I guess it could help with how data is stored in memory if that is a concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use `virtual` for fields, only for methods.

However you can simulate that by creating a function that returns a reference to a field:

```
class Base
{
private:
    int x;

public:
    virtual int& X() { return x; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    int x;

public:
    virtual int& X() override { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d;

    b->X() = 100; // will set d's x
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't override member variables with the `virtual` keyword. You could, however, have `virtual` getters and setters that refer to **different** member variables in the base and derived classes to achieve a similar effect:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    virtual void setX(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
private:
    int x;
}

class derived : public base {
public:
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    void setX(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
private:
    int x;
}
```

Comment: You've hidden, not overrode `getX` and `setX`

Comment: @Caleth indeed. Too much time in Java. Caleth's edit should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are totally fine but you can also use the much simpler syntax:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual operator int&() { return x; };
    virtual operator int() { return x; };
protected:
    int x;
};
```

if you have a single variable that you'd wish to virtualize in your class.

The second declaration is only to avoid using a reference when you just need the value, while when assigning the reference is automatically chosen for you.

You can override these operators at will from classes derived from base.

```
class derived : public base {
    public:
    operator int() override { return x * 5; };
}
```