# Reaching inherited variables with base class pointers

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, virtual-functions

I learnt the work of virtual functions: if the inherited classes inherit a function from the base class, and it is custom for each ones, I can call these functions with pointers that point to the base class, this way:

```
BaseClass* PointerName = &InheritedClassObject;
```

But what about variables? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248255/why-doesnt-c-have-virtual-variables) on the site that tells: I can't create virtual variables in C++. My experience proves it: for variables, Visual C++ says: *'virtual' is not allowed*.

Then, what is the way to reach the value of a(n inherited) variable that belongs to an inherited class by using base class pointers?

Comment: How comes your base class knows that a variable is going to be added in *every* class derived from it? (And this variable will have the same type for each derived class etc.)

Comment: I want to call variables that are inherited from the base class, and consequently all the inherited class have them.

Comment: Could you provide an example? It might be the case that there's a very simple solution to your problem.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt See my answer.  I think there may have been some confusion with the wording of the question.  if not, please tell me and I will delete my response.

Comment: @DyP My exact problem is that an expression like this: `PointerArray[Object.X][Object.Y] = &Object;` (where `Object` is an inherited class object and `X` and `Y` are inherited from base class) does nothing. The value of `PointerArray[Object.X][Object.Y]` is still the same, most certainly because neither of `X` or `Y` is called. 

@SteveP. Okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your comment, I think what you are trying to ask if how do child classes access their parent's variables.  Consider this example:

```
class Parent 
{
public:
  Parent(): x(0) {}
  virtual ~Parent() {}

protected:
  int x;
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
  Child(): Parent(), num(0) {}

private:
  int num;
};

void Child::foo() 
{
  num = x; //Gets Parent's x, 
}
```

NB:
  If you define an x in `Child`, that masks the `x` in `Parent`.  So, if you want to get the x in `Parent`, you would need: `Parent::x`.  To simply get `x` from a `Child c`, you use `c.x` if `x` is `public` or use a getter if `x` is `protected` or `private`:

```
int Child::getNum()
{
     return num;
}
```

Comment: True, I haven't programmed in C++ in quite some time.  Thanks.

Comment: In my program, the parent is necessary only for declaring variables that every inherited class owns, so it's not a problem. However, your code is not exactly clear for me: `parent()` is obviously a function, but what is `x(0) {}`? A function with the name of a variable, and a zero input? Anyway, for my exact problem, see the comment below the main post.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt it just initializes `x` to be 0.  I made an edit.  It should help.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt For the `: x(0)`, see [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Virtual functions use them, do whatever needs to be done and return result if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any function, data member of an inherited class if it's casted back to base class. However, you can alter those variables with virtual functions. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass {
public:
  BaseClass() {}
  virtual void do_smth() = 0;

private:
};

class InheritedClass: public BaseClass {
public:
  InheritedClass(): a(1) {}
  virtual void do_smth() { std::cout << ++a << std::endl; }
private:
  int a;
};

int main() {
  BaseClass* ptr = new InheritedClass();
  ptr->do_smth();
  return 0;
}
```

In this piece of code, virtual function did alteration of variable belongs to InheritedClass.